# Creating Edit Page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql

Im a newbie in asp.net and im about to do a edit page for my news and announcement page.

This is my sample code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="news_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="news_id" HeaderText="news_id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="news_id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="news" HeaderText="news" SortExpression="news" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="news_date" HeaderText="news_date" 
                SortExpression="news_date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="news_data" HeaderText="news_data" 
                SortExpression="news_data" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TDBSConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [news_id], [news], [news_date], [news_data] FROM [ibsi.news]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I put the data into a gridview to show all the data from the database.

how can i use this dataview to edit my content or can what can i use in the toolbar to create one edit module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET GridView allows for a row of data to be edited by setting the EditIndex property of the GridView, placing the entire row in edit mode....
To implement this,go throught following article of codeproject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18136/Edit-Individual-GridView-Cells-in-ASP-NET